# CMD in ps command in linux

Tags: linux, ps

Under CMD, I was wondering what the /1 or /2 ... are? What do they indicate? I couldnt find it in the man page. In general, does anyone have a good understanding of the CMD column that they could share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean when you run `ps -e -o cmd`, you can see entries like:

```
[kthreadd]
[ksoftirqd/0]
[migration/0]
[watchdog/0]
[events/0]
```

They are called "kernel threads".  Anything with `[]` around it is a kernel thread.

`/0` means it is running on the first CPU, `/1` means it is running on the second CPU, etc.

For more information, see:

- [Linux Magazine - Kernel Threads](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2195)
- [Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love, second edition, page 35](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672329468)

Answer (score 1):

They represent the core that the given kernel thread is bound to.